# Can't connect to any site on MacBook.

Tags: macbook-pro, network, internet

here is the problem. On my MacBook Pro with mavericks I can't connect to any site with working wifi(checked it on ipad). Also, Skype and utorrent are working fine, but all browsers can't connect. Restart MacBook and wifi didn't help.

Comment: Are you able to ping external websites? Open Terminal.app and run ping on some address. Try ping 8.8.8.8 (Google's public DNS). Have you tried with multiple browsers?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use Skype and uTorrent, but not able to use Safari or Chrome, I would recommend that you try [resetting the SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964). In my comment above, I recommended trying to ping external addresses which would determine the status of your network connectivity.